# /etc/network/interfaces configuration messed up

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to setup a virtualized server up with KVM on my OVH server. However, when configuring the network, I'm encountering some issues. Any help in any form is greatly appreciated!

This is my current, working setup

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address (public ip)
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network (public ip).0
        broadcast (public ip).255
        gateway (public ip).254
```

In order to set up my virtualized server, I need to set up another network for the virtualized instance to go through. So, I tried adding this to my interfaces file:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.40.134
    network 192.168.40.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.40.255
    gateway (public ip).254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

However, restarting the network setup causes the server to become inaccessible over the internet. I've tried multiple times different variations to get this to work, however, it's becoming tedious to boot the server into rescue mode, fix it, and get out.

Once again, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options that I can think of.

Remove the `auto eth0` and replace it with `auto br0`.  Configure the bridge with your public IP configuration.  If you need an internal address range add it as an extra address using `ip` or as `br0:1`.  I believe you can have only one bridge if you add an inter face to it.

Configure the bridge separate from the eth0 interface.  This is the configuration I use modified with your addresses.  You do not want to add a gateway to this interface.  You will need to configure iptables to do SNAT (masq) and forward packets.

```
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.40.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    pre-up    brctl addbr br0
    post-down brctl delbr br0
```

Configure the network in KVM and configure it to autostart.  KVM will then configure the bridge for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ip address  of your bridge to your public ip, not 192.....

Sorry, posted from my phone.

Private ip addresses are not publicly routable.

So, with

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address **(public ip)**
```

it worked as your public ip is routable.

Your second config,

```
iface br0 inet static
   address **192.168.40.134**
```

is a private ip (192.168.40.134) an not routable (unless you have a router that forwards your public ip to your private ip via port forwarding, but that is a di

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain "why"?